# Best way to specify path to binary for a wrapper module

Tags: python

I write a module that wraps functionality of an external binary.

For example, I wrap `ls` program into a python module `my_wrapper.py`

```
import my_wrapper
print my_wrapper.ls('some_directory/')
# list files in some_directory
```

and in my_wrapper.py I do:

```
# my_wrapper.py

PATH_TO_LS = '/bin/ls'

def ls(path):
    proc = subprocess.Popen([PATH_TO_LS, path], ...)
    ...
    return paths
```

(of course, I do not wrap `ls` but some other binary)

The binary might be installed with an arbitrary location, like `/usr/bin/`,  `/opt/` or even at the same place as the python script (`./binaries/`)

**Question:**

What would be the cleanest (from the user perspective) way to set the path to the binary?

- Should the user specify `my_wrapper.PATH_TO_LS = ...` or invoke some `my_wrapper.set_binary_path(path)` at the beginning of his script?
- Maybe it would be better to specify it in `env`, and the wrapper would find it with `os.environ`?
- If the wrapper is distributed as egg, can I require during the installation, that the executable is already present in the system (see below)?

egg example:

```
# setup.py
setup(
    name='my_wrapper',
    requires_binaries=['the_binary'] # <--- require that the binary is already 
                                     #      installed and on visible
                                     #      on execution path
)
```

or

```
easy_install my_wrapper BINARY_PATH=/usr/local/bin/the_binary
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a "configuration object" with sane defaults. Allow the consumer to modify the values as appropriate. Accept a configuration object instance to your functions, taking the one you created by default.

Comment: At which level? Function execution, e.g., `params = LSParameters(...); my_wrapper(params)`?

Comment: Yes. But presumably you'll have more than just one configuration option.